# How to speedup the groupby.filter() operation?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following code with groupby function

```
 order_diff = order.groupby("CD_QTY").filter(
     lambda x: x["BOX_ID"].nunique() > 1
)
```

But the filter function is very slow

I would like to use the transform or map function. But the result with both transform and map function is different than the filter function

I have tried transform() and map()

```
# tranform
oder_diff = order[order.groupby("CD_QTY")["BOX_ID"].transform('nunique').gt(1)]
```

```
#using map()
order[order["CD_QTY"].map(order.groupby("CD_QTY")["BOX_ID"].nunique()).gt(1)]
```

I am a bit confused about why the results are different than the filter(). I would appreciate your feedback on this. Thank you.

Comment: Would this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54610459/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-pandas-groupby-filter-operation

Comment: Can you share a sample of your dataframe please?

Comment: I tried the exact same approach but the shape of my data is different for filter()  as compared to map() and transform()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My rule of thumb is that any pandas function that take a custom lambda will be slowed down significantly due to looping and hence perfomance-limited by the GIL.

If you care about speed, use vectorized functions as much as possible:

```
# Some mock data
n = 10_000

np.random.seed(42)
cd_qty = np.random.randint(1, n, n)
box_id = np.random.randint(1, 5, n)

order = pd.DataFrame({
    'CD_QTY': cd_qty,
    'BOX_ID': box_id
})

# The original solution. 1.59s
order_diff_1 = order.groupby("CD_QTY").filter(
     lambda x: x["BOX_ID"].nunique() > 1
)

# Vectorized. 8.5 ms -> 187x faster
count = order.groupby(['CD_QTY'])['BOX_ID'].nunique()
cond = order['CD_QTY'].isin(count[count > 1].index)
order_diff_2 = order.loc[cond]

# Check if they produce the same outputs
all(order_diff_1 == order_diff_2) # --> True
```

Comment: you can still speed it up (by a tiny bit, about 25%) by calculating `nunique()` only on the relevant column (instead of doing it on all columns and then subsetting): `count = order.groupby(['CD_QTY'])['BOX_ID'].nunique()` (5.44ms).

Comment: @PierreD I overlooked that fact since the mock data has only 2 columns

Comment: @PierreD Thanks. I was wondering if transform('nunique').gt(1) is valid or not?

Comment: @prb07 - It is valid and faster like solution above.

Answer (score 3):

Testing and your both solutions are faster like accepted answer, here is winner [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
# Some mock data
n = 10_000

np.random.seed(42)
cd_qty = np.random.randint(1, n, n)
box_id = np.random.randint(1, 5, n)

order = pd.DataFrame({
    'CD_QTY': cd_qty,
    'BOX_ID': box_id
})

count = order.groupby(['CD_QTY'])['BOX_ID'].nunique()
cond = order['CD_QTY'].isin(count[count > 1].index)
order_diff_2 = order.loc[cond]

order_diff = order[order.groupby("CD_QTY")["BOX_ID"].transform('nunique').gt(1)]
order_diff_3 =order[order["CD_QTY"].map(order.groupby("CD_QTY")["BOX_ID"].nunique()).gt(1)]

print (all(order_diff == order_diff_2))
True
print (all(order_diff == order_diff_3))
True
```

---

```
In [201]: %%timeit
     ...: count = order.groupby(['CD_QTY'])['BOX_ID'].nunique()
     ...: cond = order['CD_QTY'].isin(count[count > 1].index)
     ...: order_diff_2 = order.loc[cond]
     ...: 
4.8 ms ± 56.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [202]: %%timeit
     ...: order[order.groupby("CD_QTY")["BOX_ID"].transform('nunique').gt(1)]
     ...: 
4.02 ms ± 50.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [203]: %%timeit
     ...: order[order["CD_QTY"].map(order.groupby("CD_QTY")["BOX_ID"].nunique()).gt(1)]
     ...: 
4.31 ms ± 40.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```